# LinkedIn share Issue: Post to company page using share-offsite URL throws error

Tags: linkedin-api

Post to company page using share-offsite URL throws Error

Unable to post to company page using LinkedIn share button in a webpage. I am a super admin on the company page that I'm trying to post via linkedIn Share so there should be no reason to prevent it.
We are using Share Plugin.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin

Error Message:
"Remove your attachment in order to post from another account" error is displayed in the pop-up window with the https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?URL=

Tried other URLs not working
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=

When trying to post on the linkedIn profile it works but while trying to switch to a LinkedInpage throws error. (Being a superadmin)

#linkedin

[image]